# College Algebra Function Transformations Unique?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, elementary-functions

Let $f(x)=x^2$ be the parent function for the transformation $g(x)=(2x+12)^2 -1$. Follow the two points $(0,0)$ and $(2,4)$ from the parent function through the transformation.

Let's simplify $g(x)$ first. So, $g(x)=(2(x+6))^2 -1$. This form tells me the transformations of the graph.

I know that the $x$-values from the parent function, call them $h$, will be transformed by $\frac{h}{2}-6$. Also, I know that the $y$-values from the parent function, call them $k$, will be transformed to $y=k-1$.

So, the points $(0,0)$ and $(2,4)$ are mapped to $(-6,-1)$ and $(-5,3)$, respectively.

Now, if I simplify $g(x)$ to $g(x)=4(x+6)^2 -1$, then parent points $(h,k)$ transform to $(h-6, 4k-1)$. So, the points $(0,0)$ and $(2,4)$ are mapped to $(-6,-1)$ and $(-4,15)$. The last point is different from what I original calculated. That is, the point $(2,4)$ was mapped to different locations on $g(z)$.

These functions are the same but simplified differently. However, the parent points are mapped to different locations on the transformed function. Why does this happen? I'm assuming that both will eventually map the entire graph of the transformed function, but I thought that the parent points would be mapped to the same set of points.

Comment: What is meant by "parent point"?

Comment: The types of transformations you're applying need not be unique. For example, we could get from $y=x$ to $y=x+1$ by translating up one unit (where $x$ stays the same and $y$ changes) or by translating left one unit (where $x$ changes and $y$ stays the same). Or by translating up $1/2$ of a unit and left $1/2$ of a unit. Your answers are both correct, and parent points need not go to the same place through the transformation.